# jQuery - How to convert div content into serialized data

Tags: jquery

I have a div and a button:

```xml
<div id="screenlist"></div>
<a href="" id="btnscreen">Add new</a>
```

Now my `jQuery` code appends to my div some sample data like this:

```
$('#btnscreen').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#screenlist')
        .append('www.sampleurl.com</br>');
 });
```

So at the end my div could look like this:

```xml
 <div id="screenlist">
www.sampleurl.com</br>
www.sampleurl.com</br>
www.sampleurl.com</br>
www.sampleurl.com</br>
www.sampleurl.com</br>
www.sampleurl.com</br>
 </div>
```

I would like to serielize the div's content so I can post that to server and get each element.

> Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply just want to serialize the current html in your `screenlist`, you can do it like,

```js
$(function() {
  var contents = $('#screenlist').html().split(/\n|\<br>/).filter(function(v) {
    return /\w+/.test(v);
  });
  var data = {};

  for (var k in contents) {
    data[k] = contents[k];
  }

  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="screenlist">
  www.sampleurl.com</br>
  www.sampleurl.com</br>
  www.sampleurl.com</br>
  www.sampleurl.com</br>
  www.sampleurl.com</br>
  www.sampleurl.com</br>
</div>
```

**Edit: (for your comments)**

It's a bad idea to parse html tags with regex, therefore I suggest an alternative approach.

```js
$(function() {
  var data = {};

  $('#screenlist > div').each(function(i, elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);
    data[$elem.attr('id')] = $elem.text();
  });

  console.log(data);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="screenlist">
  <div id=1>www.sampleurl.com</div>
  </br>
  <div id=2>www.sampleurl.com</div>
  </br>
  <div id=3>www.sampleurl.com</div>
  </br>
  <div id=4>www.sampleurl.com</div>
  </br>
  <div id=5>www.sampleurl.com</div>
  </br>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how does the split filter should be if I put the URL inside a DIV? <div id=1>www.sampleurl.com</div></br>  Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.text()`, `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/[^\n\s]+/g` to match one or more characters that are not newline character or space character, create an object with property name set to `id` of element, value set to array result of `.match()` containing each line of text followed by `<br>` within `#screenlist` element

```js
var screenlist = $("#screenlist");
var data = {
  [screenlist[0].id]: screenlist.text().match(/[^\n\s]+/g)
}
console.log(data);
// $.post("/path/to/resource", data)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id="screenlist">
  www.sampleurl.com
  <br>www.sampleurl.com
  <br>www.sampleurl.com
  <br>www.sampleurl.com
  <br>www.sampleurl.com
  <br>www.sampleurl.com
  <br>
</div>
```